# General Linear Regression: All hat matrix values are the same

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, modeling

While modelling in R using the function InfluencePlot on a model I used I got all my hat matrix values to be the same. Can anyone explain how and what this means?

```
model = glm(time~factor(word)+factor(monkey), family=Gamma(link="log"), control=glm.control(maxit=100), data=data)
hatvalues(model)
```

[image]

Comment: It probably means that each word and also each monkey occurs equally frequent.

Comment: you can check with table(monkey,word), it should give you the same value for every cell, meaning each data point has equal leverage